# How can i return different types from my method?

Tags: oop, typescript

I have a method which returns an object (`this._response`) which is of type `IResponse`. I want to return `this._response.details` which is of type `IDetails`.

```
get response(): IResponse {
    if (this._response.response.header.statusCode === "0000" || this._response.response.header.statusCode === "YHOO") {
        return this._response.details; //IDetails
    } else if (this._response.response.header.statusCode === "6621" || this._response.response.header.statusCode === "6622") {
        this._response.response.isViewError = true;        
    } else {
        this._response.response.showError = this._response.response.header;
    }
    return this._response //IResponse
}
```

> [ts] Property 'details' does not exist on type 'IResponse'.

How can I return different types from method based on if condition?

Comment: I missed the error part in my question. How is the `IResponse` defined? Does it have the `details` property? Please share the code for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
get response(): IDetails  | IResponse {
    ...
}
```

---

#### Edit

The problem with returning a union is that you'll need to check for the type of the result every time you invoke the function.

So:

```
function isResponse(obj: IDetails  | IResponse) obj is IResponse {
    return obj && obj.response;
}

let value = myObj.response;
if (isResponse(value)) {
    // value is IResponse
} else {
    // value is IDetails
}
```

Comment: I am using getter/setter, if in this case how should be the set response()?

Comment: set response(data: IResponse | IDetails) {          
        this._response = data
}

Comment: Yes, the setter and getter need to have the same type

Comment: When i change, i get the below error... Property 'response' does not exist on type 'IResponse | IDetails'. 
  Property 'response' does not exist on type 'IDetails'

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply not specify anything; the return types are automatically inferred:

[image]

the danger here is this allows you to return anything so there is no explicit guard, during development, against wrong return types.